# Retrieving data from SQLite database and display it into ListView -android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I created a database(mydb) with a table(student) in the onCreate function and then entered values dynamically using a button click.Now I want to retrieve all the data from the table student on a button click and display it into **listview**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity        
        {

        String name, phone;
            SQLiteDatabase db;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(dbname VARCHAR, dbphone VARCHAR);");

            }

            public void btnaddtodb(View v)
            {
                EditText edtxtname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtname);
                EditText edtxtphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtphone);

                name=edtxtname.getText().toString();
                phone=edtxtphone.getText().toString();

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student values('"+name+"','"+phone+"');");

                edtxtname.setText("");
                edtxtphone.setText("");

                }
          }
```

Comment: Have you tried any tutorials ?

Comment: what did you do so far? What was the trouble / error ?

Comment: tried some.. bt got confused

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this...It shows all the values in table in a LinearLayout as a list

```
try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);
        System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows.getCount());
        Integer cindex = allrows.getColumnIndex("BOOK_DATE");
        Integer cindex1 = allrows.getColumnIndex("TRIP_DATE");
        Integer cindex2 = allrows.getColumnIndex("LOCATION");

        TextView t = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
        t.setText("========================================");
        //Linear.removeAllViews();
        Linear.addView(t);

        if(allrows.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                LinearLayout id_row   = new LinearLayout(MybookingsActivity.this);
                LinearLayout book_date_row = new LinearLayout(MybookingsActivity.this);
                LinearLayout trip_date_row= new LinearLayout(MybookingsActivity.this);
                LinearLayout location_row= new LinearLayout(MybookingsActivity.this);
                LinearLayout feedback_row= new LinearLayout(MybookingsActivity.this);

                final TextView id_  = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
                final TextView book_date = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
                final TextView trip_date = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
                final TextView location = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
                final TextView sep  = new TextView(MybookingsActivity.this);
                final Button feedback  = new Button(MybookingsActivity.this);

                final String ID = allrows.getString(0);
                String BOOK_DATE= allrows.getString(1);
                String TRIP_DATE= allrows.getString(2);
                String LOCATION= allrows.getString(3);

                id_.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                id_.setPadding(20, 5, 0, 5);

                book_date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                book_date.setPadding(20, 5, 0, 5);
                trip_date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                trip_date.setPadding(20, 5, 0, 5);
                location.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                location.setPadding(20, 5, 0, 5);

                System.out.println("BOOK_DATE " + allrows.getString(cindex) + " TRIP_DATE : "+ allrows.getString(cindex1)+ " LOCATION : "+ allrows.getString(cindex2));
                System.out.println("ID : "+ ID  + " || BOOK_DATE " + BOOK_DATE + "|| TRIP_DATE : "+ TRIP_DATE+ "|| LOCATION : "+LOCATION);

                id_.setText("ID : " + ID);
                id_row.addView(id_);
                Linear.addView(id_row);
                book_date.setText("BOOK_DATE : "+BOOK_DATE);
                book_date_row.addView(book_date);
                Linear.addView(book_date_row);
                trip_date.setText("TRIP_DATE : " + TRIP_DATE);
                trip_date_row.addView(trip_date);
                Linear.addView(trip_date_row);
                location.setText("LOCATION : " + LOCATION);
                location_row.addView(location);
                Linear.addView(location_row);
                feedback.setText("Feedback");
                feedback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MybookingsActivity.this,FeedbackActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", ID);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                feedback_row.addView(feedback);
                Linear.addView(feedback_row);
                sep.setText("---------------------------------------------------------------");
                Linear.addView(sep);
            }
            while(allrows.moveToNext());
        }
        mydb.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered."+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Try it..Dont forget to change the dbname,tablename and fielnames..

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can always use the [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to show something in listview. (there is a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) about it and many other ones you can find on Internet)

For something in db, besides the basic `ArrayAdapter`, you can also use [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) which has some extra benefits such as dynamic loading and auto refresh.

To use `CursorAdapter`, Let your `Activity` implements `LoaderCallback<Cursor>` and its required callbacks.

Init a `CursorAdapter` and set it to the `ListView`.

In the `CreateLoader(...)` method, query whatever you need.

Remember to implement the `newView` and `bindView` properly.

A simplest sample may looks like below:

```
    public class TestActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
      ListView listview;
      CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;



      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, null) {

          @Override
          public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list_item, parent, false);
            bindView(rowView, context, cursor);
            return rowView;
          }

          @Override
          public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(0));

          }
        };
      }

      @Override
      public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return db.query(...);
      }

      @Override
      public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);

      }

      @Override
      public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

      }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**USE this tutorial my be it help you.**
1> [Android-sqlite-and-listview-example](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html)

2> [listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html)